# Не карантинный — пишется слитно или раздельно

Tags: частица-не

Подскажите, как правильно написать «*не карантинные вредные организмы*» — слитно или раздельно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что нужно писать слитно: с **не** образуется слово с противоположным значением (слово без **не** существует — карантинный).

Противопоставление отсутствует (**не** карантинный, **а** какой-то другой), усилительных отрицательных местоимений или наречий нет.
[НЕ с прилагательными](https://petroleks.ru/gramota/18.php)

[Официальная борьба] *Активное применение обязательных фитосанитарных регламентаций, а также применение обязательных фитосанитарных процедур в целях ликвидации или локализации карантинных вредных организмов или для управления регулируемыми [некарантинными](https://vniikr.ru/reports/reference/glossary) вредными организмами* [Приложение 1 к Глоссарию; ВКФМ, 2001].

*...в сфере карантина растений в феромонных ловушках был выявлен **некарантинный** объект — почвенный комарик.*

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, пишется **слитно**, потому что не соответствует ни одному из случаев, когда нужно писать раздельно (см. [Не с прилагательными и причастиями](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-00000000d8573f987cea4c65181925c6)). В частности, нет противопоставления, нет отрицания.

Гугл находит: 1160 слитно (некарантинные вредные организмы) и 81 раздельно (не карантинные вредные организмы).